# Draw points only without joining them using drawContours() opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Trying to get image B as shown below but below code gives image A [followed tutorial by https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/10/06/opencv-contour-approximation/]. mask refers to the green region.

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)


eps = 0.001 


peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, eps * peri, True)

#here np.array of shape [4,1,2] is got.
  
output = mask.copy()
cv2.drawContours(output, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)


cv2.putText(output, text, (x, y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Approximated Contour", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)]
```

[image]

How to get image B? I think drawContours() should not join points with a line but dont find how to get that. Opencv link https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html doesnt show the code to get image B

Comment: The contours is at the bottom line a list of x,y coordinates in the image (an array of arrays of points to be exact). You can draw them yourself in a loop (e.g. using cv2.circle).

Comment: The drawContours will connect the points.  You need to just draw circles for each point in the contour. So you need to loop over the points in the contour and use cv2.circle() to draw a "point"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('corner.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)
    
cv2.imshow('Corner',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```